# Prevent scripts from being cached programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, caching

I would like to ask if there is a way to prevent Firefox from caching scripts (.js files).

I have a project (ASP.Net Web App) with caching issue on firefox. When I first run the application (script is being cached on firefox) and modify the script and rerun the application, firefox is using the cached script instead of the updated one.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.13.

I already tried using HttpHeaders but it seems like firefox is ignoring my codes.

Here is my code:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

I tried placing this code at global.asax > Application_BeginRequest and at MasterPage.aspx.cs > Page_Load, but it isn't working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent caching for development environment only? If yes, have you tried setting Firefox to not cache anything in Tools -> Options -> Privacy tab?

Comment: a hacky workaround is to append a querystring to your script so that ff thinks it is new <script src="foo.js?version=1". You could programmatically append the current time to the script and then it will always be "new."

Comment: Hi, this issue was reported from Production of my project, so unfortunately, it isn't appropriate to tell the user to set their firefox not to cache anything. :(

Comment: @Kael Ah, in that case, I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @mrtsherman Thanks, I've already come with the querystring technique, I am just thinking if there is any more option to work this around.

Comment: @KaeL By the way, why prevent javascript from being cached?

Comment: @Magnus: Sorry for very late reply. My javascript is being updated most of the time. That's why I need to prevent it from being cached. THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

> HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

but you will have to have a http handler that renders the script directly to the response stream and than set the source url of the script tag to the handler or configure IIS to handle all javascripts using a specific handler:
**Point *.js to the aspnet_isapi.dll ISAPI Extension** and than add the following in your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <!-- javascript handler -->
        <add verb="*" path="*.js" 
         type="skmHttpHandlers.JavascriptHandler, skmHttpHandlers" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

And than the handler:

```
namespace skmHttpHandlers
{
   public class JavascriptHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
         context.Response.Clear();
         context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
         using (var scriptStream = File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/script/TheScript.js"), FileMode.Open))
           scriptStream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
         context.Response.End();
      }

      public bool IsReusable
      {
         get
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I'm new to HttpHandlers. I'm searching on how to render script using that, but no luck. Can you show me a sample code?

Comment: Thanks Magnus for the codes. I'll be looking into this and post my updates after testing this. :)

Comment: Hi I tested this one but firefox still doesn't update the script. Here is my code (I'm not 100% sure if I'm doing the right thing, but I was able to render the script using HttpHandler).

Comment: @Web.config:
`<!-- I did a single file path only -->
      <add verb="*" path="*../Scripts/JScript.js" type="Namespace.ScriptHandler, Namespace"/>
`

Comment: @ScriptHandler: `context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
   
   
            string script = "<script language='javascript' src='" + context.Request.ApplicationPath + "/Scripts/JScript.js'>></script>";
            script = script.Replace("//", "/");
            context.Response.Write(script);`

Comment: Then @MasterPage.aspx.cs > Page_Load: `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ScriptHandler sh = new ScriptHandler();
            sh.ProcessRequest(new HttpContext(HttpContext.Current.Request, HttpContext.Current.Response));
}`

Comment: @KaeL You should render the script not the link to the script, see my edit. An then just register the script tag as usual on the page. The handler will load instead of the script file, and then the handler renders the script without cache.

Comment: Hi, how should I set the source url of the script tag to the handler? I'm trying this one: `<script language='javascript' src='<% sh.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current) %>'></script>` but is not referring to the script. Sorry for my questions (I feel like I'm very stupid XD)

Comment: If handler is set up correctly in IIS and Webconfig you would only need to write <script language='javascript' src='scrips/TheScript.js'>
The handler will run for all files of type *.js (in my example)

Comment: Hi, correct me if I'm wrong, so after setting up my webconfig, creating the Handler and adding the normal `<script>` in my page, do I need to invoke the `Handler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current)` and where should I invoke that function? And should I still set up the IIS even if I already had set up my Web.config? I'm afraid I've no control at IIS in our Production Site. Thanks again and again :D

Comment: Hi I was able to test this code and its working! Thanks, I learned a lot from you with regards to HttpHandlers. :D

Answer (score 3):

One technique is to add a random element to the URL as a querystring, so the browser doesn't know how to cache the script:

```
<script src="jquery.js?<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" />
```

Even better would be to append the current build number of your assembly, so you get the performance benefits of script caching while the script hasn't changed. This only works however, if you never change your script files "out of band" with your binary releases.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. :D I've already tried this one (querystring) and it solves the caching issue, but i'm looking for a more programmatic way if there is any, like setting it from code behind.

Comment: You can alwyas use RegisterClientScriptBlock from codebehind and than add the Ticks

Comment: @Magnus: What I mean is if there are any other options rather than using querystring which I can set from code behind. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

1) Install IIS module: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

2) Put this in web.config into  section:

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Style Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^v(.*?)/styles/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/styles/{R:2}" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Javascript Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^v(.*?)/javascript/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/javascript/{R:2}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

3) Write this helper function (into some global class)

```
public static string PutCSS(string filepath)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filepath));
    string timestamp = f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Year.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Month.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Day.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Hour.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Minute.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Second.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Millisecond.ToString();
    return "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"v" + timestamp + "/" + filepath + "\" />\n";
}

public static string PutJS(string filepath)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filepath));
    string timestamp = f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Year.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Month.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Day.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Hour.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Minute.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Second.ToString() + f.LastWriteTimeUtc.Millisecond.ToString();
    return "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"v" + timestamp + "/" + filepath + "\" ></script>\n";
}
```

4) Instead of:

```
<link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/userscript.js" ></script>
```

Use:

```
<%= global.PutCSS("Styles/style.css")%>
<%= global.PutCSS("Javascript/userscript.css")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the IIS configuration then you can put all your scripts inside one folder and tell IIS to expire the content immediately, or add other custom headers of your choice.

The appropriate page for IIS 6.0 is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732442.aspx

Comment: Hi I've already come up with HttpHeader configuration at IIS, but we have issues in controlling IIS in our Production Site. But definitely this will work. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<head runat="server">
    <%= "<link href='/asset/Style.css?v" + new Random().Next(1000,9999).ToString() + "' rel='stylesheet' />" %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I WANT the scripts and the styles to be cached... only reload them when they change... It is easy using the date of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/custom.js?d=@(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath("~/js/custom.js")).ToString(),"[^0-9]", ""))"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/custom.css?d=@(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath("~/css/custom.css")).ToString(),"[^0-9]", ""))" />
```